# Toggle dropdown list in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 7 options in my dropdown list.if I select one  option it's display content of selected one along with others content so can any one tell me code

Comment: What have u tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I think its because items works asynchronously. So you are must place setTimeout in click listener like that:

```
$('item').click = function() {
setTimeout(function(){
    #('item').click();
}, 1);
}
```

In this situation I often use my favourite nodeJS

Comment: No I don't want to do timeout.I wanted do like if I select option 4 means it should I hide other option content

Comment: oh sorry i dont understand your question at first time. so u can place four divs, and select their in array by JS. and than after click u must increase z-index to show your div. like this:

var divs = $('.div-class);

$('select').click = function(){
  //var ind = index of clicked element
  divs[ind].css('z-index') = divs[ind].css('z-index') + 100;
}

Comment: Can u write it with example please